# Ошибка при запуске программ по RDP

Tags: windows, сервер, сеть, rdp

- Windows Server 2008 R2
- ActiveDirectory с подтягиванием профилей
- Внешние подключения идут через шлюз, внутренние на прямую

С недавних пор, при подключении по RDP с запуском программы при старте, начала на всех терминальных серверах вылазить ошибка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

при этом

- если не закрывая ошибку, через диспетчер, запустить эту же программу
- все работает если зайти сначала на рабочий стол и потом запустить
- программу все работает не важно находится программа локально или на
  сетевом ресурсе
- не важно что это за программа
- на всех терминалах сразу

не пойму что происходит, помогите?

Comment: ну как бы Вы сами должны понимать, что информации в вопросе недостаточно. Версия оси, доступ к терминалкам через локальную сеть\интернет(впн), терминальный шлюз или каждый сервер сам по себе, домен, если домен - хранятся ли профили на каждом сервере отдельно или подтягиваются...

Comment: добавил описание

Comment: Да, информации мало, но
Проверьте  лицензирование терминального сервера.
возможно есть проблемы в реестре 
 "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\WinStations

Comment: или попробуй в AD свойствах пользователя-> вкладка "среда" указать путь к твоему приложению

Comment: Эта ошибка появляется при запуске любой программы. Так же после появления ошибки программу можно запустить.

Comment: а если сделать отложенный запуск программы? типа батника @echo off
timeout /t 10 /nobreak
start "" "путь"

Answer (score 0):

**ВОПРОС РЕШИЛСЯ**

Запретил на шлюзе запуск не опубликованных программ из за чего при любом подключении кроме RemoteApp все блокировалось.